# Adding CSV value to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, visual-studio, csv

I want to add CSV values to an array but I got this error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"/Users/ghost/Desktop/test.csv"))
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        List<string> listB = new List<string>();

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');
            listA.Add(values[0]);
            listB.Add(values[1]);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The File could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: One of the lines read has no ; in it. (and this is not the way to do it)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is that one of the lines doesn't have a semicolon in it. Thus `Split` returns an array of length `1`. Accessing `values[1]` of such an array will throw.

You can fix this by testing the size of the returned array and taking appropriate action.

```
var line = reader.ReadLine();
var values = line.Split(';'); 
listA.Add(values[0]); 
if (values.Length > 1)
   listB.Add(values[1]);
```

Perhaps you want a default value of blank:

```
if (values.Length > 1)
   listB.Add(values[1]);
else
   listB.Add(string.Empty);
```

Or you *could* also skip the line entirely. How you do it is up to you, but you *must* be prepared to handle such cases especially if you don't control the data's generation (for example, it's provided by a user or an external service).

If you are dealing with a lot of CSV files I suggest not trying to do it yourself, perhaps instead opting for a third-party library like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). You can also use .NET's `TextFieldParser` which--while not as robust-- handles CSV logic a lot better than manual solutions.

Answer (score 0):

obviously one line doesn't contain an `;` so that `values[1]` is invalid on that line.

Comment: Yes you are right. i have to put ','. thank you bro

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is nothing after or before one of the semicolons in you csv file, and thats why you are getting the error. The error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array" comes from one of these two lines:

```
listA.Add(values[0]);
listB.Add(values[1]);
```

Comment: No text before or after wouldn't matter here as the post does not use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. Even the line ";" would have two values (both empty) The answer is that one of the lines doesn't have a semicolon in it and thus returns an array of size 1

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an array immediately because you need to know the number of rows from the beginning (and this would require to read the csv file twice)

You can store values in two `List<T>` and then use them or convert into an array using `List<T>.ToArray()`

```
var column1 = new List<string>();
var column2 = new List<string>();
using (var rd = new StreamReader("filename.csv"))
{
    while (!rd.EndOfStream)
    {
        var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(';');
        column1.Add(splits[0]);
        column2.Add(splits[1]);
    }
}
// print column1
Console.WriteLine("Column 1:");
foreach (var element in column1)
    Console.WriteLine(element);

// print column2
Console.WriteLine("Column 2:");
foreach (var element in column2)
    Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a check to get rid of the exception.

```
var values = line.Split(';');
if(values.Length != 1)
{
    listA.Add(values[0]);
    listB.Add(values[1]);
}
```

Comment: This code will fail if `string.Split()` returns an array with zero elements. You should always program defensively for unexpected values.

Comment: can you provide example where it will return an array with zero elements? @JonathanWood

Answer (score 0):

First off, `StreamReader.ReadLine()` returns null when you've reached the end of the file, so use that to figure out when you're done reading all the lines.

Second, arrays have a `Length` property. Use it to see how many elements it contains. Don't use `array[1]` when the array only has one or zero elements.

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    var values = line.Split(';');
    if (values.Length >= 2)
    {
        listA.Add(values[0]);
        listB.Add(values[1]);
    }
    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Also, some CSV files can include semicolons or newlines within the fields. So `string.Split()` is not always enough. For more sophisticated handling of delimited files, you might want to check out my [SoftCircuits.CsvParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftCircuits.CsvParser/) NuGet package.